# YUI doesn't fire on.change when using bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yui

I'm in a position where I am having to use jQuery and YUI within the same project. I am using Bootstrap multiselect - http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

I am trying the below YUI code:

```
this.level1 = this.Y.one("#menu");
this.level1.on('change',this.getAjax,this);
```

Now, this works when the dropdown menu is NOT Multiselect enabled. Once it is, `getAjax` is not fired.

Any ideas? I'm guessing (from Google Inspect) the actual menu is not being changed?

When I try to use jQuery to see if something has changed, I can get it to work but get an error when trying to run getAjax()

```
$('#menu').on('change', function(evt, params){
    this.getAjax();
}
```

Error is

```
this.getAjax is not a function(…)
```

Larger snippet of code

```
constructor: function() {

    $('#menu').on('change', function(evt, params){
        this.getAjax();
    });

},

/**
 * Sample widget method.
 */
methodName: function() {

},

/**
 * Makes an AJAX request for `default_ajax_endpoint`.
 */
 getAjax: function() {
```

So I can see if it changes via jQuery but how would I then call `getAjax`?

Comment: Because multiselect component has own change event hence it doesn't fire you should use multiselect plugin event onChange http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange

Comment: I can't get that to fire the YUI function though - that's where the issue lies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access in this from any event because that time "this" is referenced to your item, hence you should use below

```
constructor: function() {
var $this = this;
$('#menu').on('change', function(evt, params){
    //this.getAjax();//this is your '#menu' item
    $this.getAjax();
});

    },

    /**
     * Sample widget method.
     */
    methodName: function() {

    },

    /**
     * Makes an AJAX request for `default_ajax_endpoint`.
     */
     getAjax: function() {
```